# Select dates within the last week, but not only last 7 days

Tags: mysql, date, select

I want to select all dates within the last week.
But not by simply counting the current date - 7, as all posts Ive come across suggest.
This is how I actually have it for the SUM now....

```
SELECT SUM(total) FROM payforms WHERE user_id = 1 GROUP BY WEEK(date)
```

This gives me a nice total...
But I want to retrieve all individual records within the last week.
So I can use a BETWEEN query....but how do I get it to look in the current week.
Example...
Tuesday I want it to only find values from Sun, Mon, Tue.
On wednesday, I want it to find Sun, Mon, Tue, Wed.
On Saturday it finds the whole previous week. etc

So to be more clear....
I dont want it to find last Monday, on a monday.
On Mondays it should only display Mondays, if you get what I mean.

Can I do this??

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from payforms where yearweek(date) = yearweek(now());
```

Although I think MySQL weeks start on Sunday

Comment: It starts on monday, from the [Weekday](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_weekday) function `Returns the weekday index for date (0 = Monday, 1 = Tuesday, … 6 = Sunday).`

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the [**WEEKDAY**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_weekday) date function, which returns the day index of the week.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you could use this query:

```
SELECT   date, SUM(total)
FROM     payforms
WHERE    date >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE())-1 DAY
GROUP BY date
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/167b8/1).
This will SUM all totals for every day of the current week, starting on last Sunday. If you want it to start on last Monday you can use this:

```
WHERE    date >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL WEEKDAY(CURDATE()) DAY
```